# Outlook Add in in Outlook 2016 installation failed?

Tags: outlook, office365, outlook-addin, office-addins

I have build a custom web app add in for outlook. I am trying to add the Manifest file from a URL where I have deployed it on a server.
The problem is when I add the manifest file from my computer it gets installed correctly, but when I try to install it from the URL, it gives me error  [image]
installation failed
An internal server error occurred. The operation failed., No such host is know.

Comment: The error says clearly "no such host is known". You would need to look at the manifest you have deployed. All your URLs must be HTTPS; take the URL and try to reach any resource with browser, see if it accessible; do same check for URL where you deployed your manifest.

Comment: See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/testing/troubleshoot-manifest  and use the manifest troubleshooter